# SQL - Updating / Computing values from different rows but same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table / dataset that looks like this:

```
headerid personid accountid value
---------------------------------
123      P1       Account1  5000
123      P1       Account2  1000
123      P2       Account1  3000
123      P2       Account2  500
```

I would like to update accountid = account1 with the difference of account1 and account2 for the same personid (p1) and headerid (123). After running the script the resulting data should look like:

```
headerid personid accountid value
---------------------------------
123      P1       Account1  4000
123      P1       Account2  1000
123      P2       Account1  2500
123      P2       Account2  500
```

Thing to note is I need to update all person's account1 values with the script. I am using SQL SERVER 2017.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck? Can there be multiple rows for a person and account or is the pair the primary key? Does the header ID matter? Can ther be persons with an Account1 and no Account2? Can there be persons with an Account2 and no Account1? Do other accounts exist in the table?

Comment: tried something with inner select like:
update sourcetable set value = value - (select value from sourcetable where accountid = 'account2' and headerid = @headerid) ) , I just cant get the specific row per specific person. . Also tried with cross join but i dont know how to update using CROSS JOIN.

Comment: A unique row would consist of combination of headerid personid and accountid . 
And yes , 1 personid can have other accounts other then account1 and account2. But in this instance i just need to update the value for accountid: account1 . 
A person could also have a value for account1 but no account 2, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data

```
DROP 
  TABLE IF EXISTS #mytable;
  CREATE TABLE #mytable(
  headerid VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  personid VARCHAR(50), 
  accountid VARCHAR(50), 
  value int
);
INSERT INTO #mytable(headerid,personid,accountid,value) VALUES 
('123', 'P1', 'Account1', 5000), 
('123', 'P1', 'Account2', 1000), 
('123', 'P2', 'Account1', 3000), 
('123', 'P2', 'Account2', 500);
```

You should *join* your *table* with *itself* in order to subtract values as follows

```
UPDATE m1
SET    m1.value = m1.value - m2.value
FROM   mytable m1
       JOIN mytable m2
         ON m1.headerid = m2.headerid
            AND m1.personid = m2.personid
            AND m1.accountid = 'Account1'
            AND m2.accountid = 'Account2'
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use conditional aggregation to determine whether `accountid` equals `Account1` or not, along with `SUM() OVER ()` window function as grouping by the `headerid` and `personid` columns

```sql
WITH t2 AS
(
 SELECT *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN accountid = 'Account1' THEN value ELSE -value END)
           OVER(PARTITION BY headerid, personid) AS new_value
   FROM t
)
UPDATE t2
   SET value = new_value
  FROM t2
 WHERE t2.accountid = 'Account1'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8307fee10b3de452336a960f0a1cb4f)</kbd>

Comment: You don't need to self-join, you can update `t2` directly. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8307fee10b3de452336a960f0a1cb4f